# Swift: Detect when SKSpriteNode has even touched

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode

I have a game where an object falls from the top of the screen to the bottom randomly. I want to have it to where if the object is tapped, I can tell it to do something, like add points to the score.

Can you help me try to figure this out? I'll be on to answer any questions if you happen to have any. Here is the code I'm using:

```
class GameSceneTest: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {



override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = SKColor.clearColor()
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
   //Change duration
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(addObject), SKAction.waitForDuration(1)])
        ))
    //AddMusicHere
}

func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
}
func random(min min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return random() * (max - min) + min
}

func add Object() {


    let Object = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Object\(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1).png")
    Object.userInteractionEnabled = true
    Object.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    Object.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Object.size)
    Object.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

    //Determine where to spawn gem across y axis
    let actually = random(min: Object.size.width/2, max: size.width - Object.size.width/2)
    //Position Object slightly off screen along right edge
    //and along random y axis point
    //Object.position = CGPoint(x: size.width + Object.size.width/2 , y: actually)
    Object.position = CGPoint(x: actually, y: size.height + Object.size.height/2)
    //Add the Object to the scene
    addChild(Object)
    //Determines speed of Object (edit later to where speed depends on type of Object)
    let actualDuration = random(min: CGFloat(4), max: CGFloat(5))
    //Create the Actions
    let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: actually, y: gem.size.height/2), duration: NSTimeInterval(actualDuration))
    let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let loseAction = SKAction.runBlock() {
        let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5) //Change to flipe vertical
        let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, won: false)
        self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: reveal)
    }



    Object.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, loseAction, actionMoveDone]))



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at "Moving The Cards Around The Board" in the following tutorial: [Ray Wenderlicht SpriteKit Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/125046/card-game-mechanics-in-sprite-kit-with-swift).

Then read a bit more around handling touch events in iOS (e.g. [Handling Touches...](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435)).

Then try something in code and if you get stuck post a more specific question - because this one is a little too general.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this!

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been dealing with this problem for a couple of days and this fixed it!